# IPC$ Block By Firewall

Tags: windows-7, windows-firewall

I have two active domain in my work place, the main console PC is in domain A while the active server is in workgroup.

The active server needs to connect to console PC's folder using the following bat file;

```
net use \\IP Address\IPC$ /user:domain\username password /persistent:yes
```

The connection works if the console PC has its "Home or Work" firewall turn off. If I were to turn that on, the connection would not pass through.

I do not think it is any services I did not turn on, right?

Answer (score 1):

As the administrator, open an administrative command prompt. Execute the following:

```
netsh advfirewall firewall set rule group="Windows management instrumentation (wmi)" new enable=yes  
netsh advfirewall firewall set rule group="file and printer sharing" new enable=yes
```

Now you should be able to connect to it.